# How to subscribe to Action property change with scala.swing listenTo?

Tags: swing, scala, events, properties, javabeans

I have a [scala.swing Action](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.swing.Action) with a custom property `mydomain.color`. I would like to repaint a button which is bound to this Action whenever the property is changed. It should be possible to subscribe to [PropertyChangeEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html), however `Action` is not a [Publisher](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.swing.Publisher), therefore it cannot be used for `listenTo`.

It would be possible to do it a normal Java way and to [write a Property Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html), but is there perhaps some shorter way? Can Java beans be used as  Publishers for scala.swing `listenTo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property change listener can be used to transform the Java beans event into a swing one and publish it, it is not that difficult:

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._
import java.beans.{PropertyChangeListener, PropertyChangeEvent}

case class PropertyChanged(source: AnyRef, propertyName: String, oldValue: AnyRef, newValue: AnyRef) extends Event

trait ActionPropertyPublisher extends Action with Publisher {
  actionPublisher =>

  class ListenToPropertyChange extends PropertyChangeListener {
    override def propertyChange(evt: PropertyChangeEvent): Unit = {
      assert(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread)
      assert(evt.getSource==actionPublisher.peer)
      publish(new PropertyChanged(actionPublisher,evt.getPropertyName,evt.getOldValue,evt.getNewValue))
    }
  }

  peer.addPropertyChangeListener(new ListenToPropertyChange())
}
```